# jquery week calendar change prev week and next week button to prev day and next day

Tags: jquery-week-calendar

I am using the following calendar in my application
[jquery-week-calendar](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)

I want to change prev and next button such that when it is clicked it goes to prev and next day other than prev and next week.

I am new to jquery and I was able to find some part of the code which leads to this.

```
  prevWeek : function() {
     //minus more than 1 day to be sure we're in previous week - account for daylight savings or other anomolies
     var newDate = new Date(this.element.data("startDate").getTime() - (MILLIS_IN_WEEK / 6));
     this._clearCalendar();
     this._loadCalEvents(newDate);
  },

  /*
   * Go to the next week relative to the currently displayed week
   */
  nextWeek : function() {
     //add 8 days to be sure of being in prev week - allows for daylight savings or other anomolies
     var newDate = new Date(this.element.data("startDate").getTime() + MILLIS_IN_WEEK + (MILLIS_IN_WEEK / 7));
     this._clearCalendar();
     this._loadCalEvents(newDate);
  }



   _loadCalEvents : function(dateWithinWeek) {

     var date, weekStartDate, endDate, $weekDayColumns;
     var self = this;
     var options = this.options;
     date = dateWithinWeek || options.date;
     weekStartDate = self._dateFirstDayOfWeek(date);
     weekEndDate = self._dateLastMilliOfWeek(date);

     options.calendarBeforeLoad(self.element);

     self.element.data("startDate", weekStartDate);
     self.element.data("endDate", weekEndDate);

     $weekDayColumns = self.element.find(".wc-day-column-inner");

     self._updateDayColumnHeader($weekDayColumns);

     //load events by chosen means
     if (typeof options.data == 'string') {
        if (options.loading) options.loading(true);
        var jsonOptions = {};
        jsonOptions[options.startParam || 'start'] = Math.round(weekStartDate.getTime() / 1000);
        jsonOptions[options.endParam || 'end'] = Math.round(weekEndDate.getTime() / 1000);
        $.getJSON(options.data, jsonOptions, function(data) {
           self._renderEvents(data, $weekDayColumns);
           if (options.loading) options.loading(false);
        });
     }
     else if ($.isFunction(options.data)) {
        options.data(weekStartDate, weekEndDate,
              function(data) {
                 self._renderEvents(data, $weekDayColumns);
              });
     }
     else if (options.data) {
           self._renderEvents(options.data, $weekDayColumns);
        }

     self._disableTextSelect($weekDayColumns);


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have add rest of functionality in your calender :

you can do this using :

```
 prevWeek : function() {

     var newDate = new Date(this.element.data("startDate"));
     newDate = this._addDays(newDate , -1);
     this._clearCalendar();
     this._loadCalEvents(newDate);
  },

  nextWeek : function() {

     var newDate = new Date(this.element.data("startDate"));
     newDate = this._addDays(newDate , 1);
     this._clearCalendar();
     this._loadCalEvents(newDate);
  }
```